# Python equivalent for Rowsums

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

[image]

**Sample data**

I have a R-code and I wanted to convert it to a similar python code. This is the R code snippet:

```
data$total <- ifelse(data$dpd_gt_30 == 1 , rowSums(data[0:2]),
                 ifelse(data$dpd_gt_30 == 3 , rowSums(data[2:4]),1000))
```

What I am doing :

```
data['total']=data.iloc[:, 0:2].sum(axis=1).where(data['dpd_gt_30'] == 1,1000)
```

How do I add multiple (more than 2 if required) conditions to this?

**Edit:**

I followed the instruction and did this:

```
conds = [
    df['dpd_gt_30'] == 1, 
    df['dpd_gt_30'] == 3,
    df['dpd_gt_30'] not in [1,3]
]

choices = [
    df.iloc[:,0:2].sum(axis=1),
    df.iloc[:,2:4].sum(axis=1),
    1000
    ]

df['Total'] = np.select(conds, choices)
```

Now how do I take care of the values which don't fall into the conditions? (Cases where the value is neither 1 or 3)

Comment: What does the rowSums function achieve? What are you actually trying to do to your data?

Comment: @Lou, rowSums sums the row if there's a matching condition, in my case if column  dpd_gt_30 is 1 I wanted to sum column [0:2] , if column dpd_gt_30 is 3, I wanted to sum column [2:4]

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.where`:

```
data['total'] = np.where(data['dpd_gt_30']==1, data.iloc[:,:2].sum(axis=1),
                         data.iloc[:,2:].sum(axis=1)
                        )
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but I have more than 2 conditions and this was just a sample snippet. I have mentioned this in the question as well.

Comment: For more than 2 conditions, use `np.select`.